# Create a custom API to get all details of a product magento2

Tags: magento2, api, products, rest-api

I want to create a custom API to get all of the information of a product including stock details and order details.

I checked the existing product APIs but to get all of the information, need to run at least 3 APIs "/V1/products", "/V1/stockItems" and "/V1/orders".

I want the responses of these 3 APIs into a single API.